# Google Analytics on AMP Story

Tags: google-analytics, amp-story

can anyone help me to put google analytic code on amp story? Amp-story does not support GA code? I have put it like this.

```xml
<amp-analytics type="gtag" data-credentials="include">
    <script type="application/json">
        {
            "vars" : {
              "gtag_id": "G-XXXXXXXXXX",
              "config" : {
                "G-XXXXXXXXXX": { "groups": "default" }
              }
            }
        }
    </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

But it seems does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the issue. Amp Story does not support Google Analytic 4 yet. If we use UA-XXXXXXX-X this code it works but G-XXXXXXXXXX does  not work.

Comment: As of June 27, Google Analytics 4 works with AMP documents. See https://twitter.com/googleanalytics/status/1673697311891812354 and https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/13707678

Answer (score 1):

Please add AMP analytic script first. Following is the google sample AMP snippet.

```
<script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
<amp-analytics type="gtag" data-credentials="include">
<script type="application/json">
{
  "vars" : {
    "gtag_id": "<GA_MEASUREMENT_ID>",
    "config" : {
      "<GA_MEASUREMENT_ID>": { "groups": "default" }
    }
  }
}
</script>
</amp-analytics>
```

Also read following.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics
[image]

Comment: I have already added <script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script> on <head> but it is not working